# HTML input field placeholder text cut off at the end

Tags: html, css, padding, placeholder, input-field

I have an HTML input form with a field with placeholder text that gets cut off at the end, beyond the padding.

[image]

I can't locate what's causing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question. It turns out it is not caused by any of my custom CSS:

[image]

It turns out it is caused by the Chrome "X" button in the input field:

[image]

The only way to remove this is to add the experimental CSS pseudo-element [`::-webkit-search-cancel-button`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-search-cancel-button) and set its `display` to `none`. I won't be doing this though.

```
::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
    display: none;
}
```

Sharing this to help anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of `text-overflow: ellipsis;`. The `text-overflow` CSS property sets how hidden overflow content is showed to users. It can be clipped, display an ellipsis ('…'), or display a custom string. You can refer to the kink below to see an example:

[text-overflow in textbox](https://jsfiddle.net/simurai/TjGyz/)